# Custom order SQL values in drop down menu

Tags: php, sql, drop-down-menu, sql-order-by

I need some help ordering values in a dropdown menu as i cannot seem to do it right myslef.

Basically, i am loading about a hundred values from SQL in a dropdown menu and i am using this statement to order at this moment:

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN title= 'Other' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, title ASC";
```

So now the values are shown alphabetically like this:

```
AAAA
BBBB
CCCC
....
....
Other
```

What i need to do is to give several values the first 4 places in the drop down, then have a bar like "------" and then show the rest of the values aplhabetically placing the "Other" at the bottom again:

```
BBBB
DDDD
HHHH
TTTT
----
AAAA
CCCC
EEEE
....
....
Other
```

I will appreacite any feedback, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You are going to need an ordering column. Else you will need a view giving you the ordering number. Something along the lines of

```
CREATE VIEW myView(ord,title) AS
    SELECT 1,"BBBB" FROM Table1
    UNION
    SELECT 2,"DDDD" FROM Table1
    UNION
    SELECT 3,"HHHH" FROM Table1
    UNION
    SELECT 3,"TTTT" FROM Table1
    UNION
    SELECT 5,"----" FROM Table1
    UNION
    SELECT 6,title FROM Table1 WHERE title NOT IN ("BBBB","DDDD","HHHH","TTTT")
    UNION
    SELECT 7,"Other" FROM Table1;
```

You can then `SELECT * FROM myView ORDER BY ord, title ASC`. You are going to have to handle the "----" though if it is selected.

Answer (score 0):

1. Load all the values from the DB in alphabetic order into PHP array or such
2. Remove your "special values" from the array
3. Build a new array where you first add the custom 4, then everything from your array and finally the "Other"
4. Use the new array to create the drop down

Instead of "---" you could use [optgroup](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/optgroup).